# How do I remove the blank line from element generated via XML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm modifying an xml.config file, and it is generating a blank line above a link.  Not sure why its happening.  How can I have it removed?

Here is the xml.config code for the list element:

```
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />
                <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) != 0">
                    <!-- <span class="catMark">&gt;&gt;</span>&#160; -->
                </xsl:if>
                <a href="{concat('c-',EntityID,'-',ise:FormatStringForLink(SEName),'.aspx')}">
                    <xsl:if test="EntityID = $CategoryID or descendant::Entity/EntityID = $CategoryID">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">font-weight:bold</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                </a>


                <xsl:if test="count(child::Entity)&gt;0 and (EntityID = $CategoryID or descendant::Entity/EntityID = $CategoryID)">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Entity">
                            <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix, '&#160;&#0160;')"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:if>
            </li>
```

When the page loads, it turns into this:

```
<li>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="c-56-holiday.aspx">Holiday</a>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a complete (but small) transformation and a complete (but small) XML document, so that by performing the transformation on the XML document everyone would be able to repro the problem -- otherwise when people are forced to guess, the results typically aren't good

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I've edited the question, I hope its more clear.  Anything else you need?  I'm brand new to XML/XSL.  Just let me know.

Comment: No, there isn't enough data to reproduce the problem. We need the source XML document (as small as possible), the complete transformation (as small as possible) and the wanted result. Then we copy and paste this data and run the transformation to repro the problem. If we can't repro the problem, there is no problem at all. Even after your update this information is missing. Please, update and provide the missing information.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Ok, I'm trying to get the source XML for this. When I get it, I'll comment again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove newline character/white space from xml using xslt or xquery transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803218/remove-newline-character-white-space-from-xml-using-xslt-or-xquery-transformatio)