# Remove newline character/white space from xml using xslt or xquery transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

How to remove newline character/white space from xml using xslt or xquery transformation.Means all the elements will come in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xslt, you can add a top level element

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

By using a sample input XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <a>XXX</a>
    <b>YYY</b>
    <c>ZZZ</c>
</root>
```

and the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- this is called an identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><a>XXX</a><b>YYY</b><c>ZZZ</c></root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,can you please send  full xslt ,which i have to use for that requirement .it will be very helpful

Comment: @Dip note that `strip-space` only removes text nodes from the input that consist _entirely_ of whitespace, it won't delete new lines that are part of a larger text node with other characters, e.g. `<foo>(NL)something(NL)</foo>`

Comment: See this (http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbq). It works on Saxon 9.5.1.3, Saxon 6.5.5, and Xalan 2.7.1

Comment: OSB? Order of St Benedict?